# Finding a specific curve via biholomorphic functions

Tags: complex-analysis

I am stuck at an exercise concerning biholomorphic functions.

> Let $U$ be a domain and $f:U \to \mathbb{C}$ be a holomorphic map. We consider  the set $M:=  \{ z \in U | f(z) \in \mathbb{R} \}$. Let $z_0 \in M$.
>
> a) Show that if $f’(z_0) \neq 0$ then there exists a neighborhood $V \subset U$ of $z_0$ such that $M \cap V$ is the image of a curve $\gamma (0,1) \to \mathbb{C}$.
>
> b) Assume that $f’(z_0)=0$ and that the function $f-f(z_0)$ has a zero at $z_0$ of order $n \geq 2$. Show that there is a neighborhood $V \subset U$ of $z_0$ such that $M \cap V$ is the union of $n$ curves whose intersection angles at $z_0$ are integer multiples of $\frac{2\pi}{n} $.

I tried to solve this as follows:

a) Because  $f’(z_0) \neq 0$ I can conclude that $f$ is locally biholomorphic. Then there are neighborhoods $V, W \subset  U$ where $ z_0 \in V,  f(z_0) \in W$ such that

$$f: V \to W \ \text{is bijective with holomorphic inverse} \ g: W \to V .$$

Now I wanted to show that $ M \cap V $ is connected. Because $f(M \cap V)  \subset \mathbb{R} $ this will imply that  $ f(M \cap V) $ is an intervall. But then I can find a curve $\delta: (0,1) \to \mathbb{R} $ where $\delta((0,1))= f(M \cap V) $. Then I can define $\gamma=g \circ  \delta $ which is the needed curve.

My problem is that I do not see how to show that $ M \cap V $ is connected.

b) I know that $g(z):=f(z)-f(z_0)$ has a zero at $z_0$ of order $n \geq 2$. This implies that there is a neighborhood $V$ of $z_0$ such that there exists a holomorphic function $h$ with

$$h(z_0)=0 \\ h’(z_0) \neq 0 \\ g(z)=(h(z))^n$$

for all z $\in V$. Because $h$ is a holomorphic n-th root of $f$ there are n possible solutions for $h$. So by a) I have

$$ \text{neighborhoods} \ V_1, …,V_n \ \text{and} \\ \text{curves} \ \gamma_1,…, \gamma_n \ \text{such that} \ \gamma_i(0,1)=f(M \cap V_i) \ \text{for} \ i=1,...,n$$.

But I do not see how to proceed as I do not see how to prove that $\cup \gamma_i(0,1)= M \cap V$ or that I get the correct angles.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should assume that $f(z_0) \in \mathbb{R}$ so that the intersections you look at are not empty. By translation, say that $f(z_0)=0$.

1) $M\cap V = g(\mathbb{R} \cap f(V))$ where $g$ is the local inverse of $f$. Choose $\varepsilon >0$ small enough so that $f : V \to D(f(z_0),\varepsilon)=D(0,\varepsilon)$ is biholomorphic. Thus $\mathbb{R}\cap D(0,\varepsilon) = ]-\varepsilon,\varepsilon[$ is connected, and $M \cap V = g(]-\varepsilon,\varepsilon[)$ is connected as the image of a connected set by a continuous function.

2) By a suitable change of coordinates, you just have to study $f(z) = z^n$ near $0$ (that is what is suggested : $h$ is a local biholomorphism). The infinitesimal angles between curves do not change with biholomorphic maps as they are conformal.

Comment: When I study f near 0 as you suggested I get for $f(z)=z^n=w$ that $z=(r e^{i(\varphi +2 \pi \ k)})^{\frac{1}{n}}, \ k=0,1,...,n-1$. So I get $n$ rays, each of which passing through 0 and one of the possible solutions. This suggests that I should consider the curves parametrizing these rays. But the issue is that this is tied to a specific value w, so this is likely not going to cover all of $M \cap V$. Therefore I’m still not quite sure how to define the curves.